# Can an iOS app receive data from any bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

So my question is can we create an iOS app that can receive data from any bluetooth devices? Even the devices we buy it form eBay?

Any encoding when the data sent from the devices make us can not decode them? Or another description : Can the bluetooth device limit the app that can connect to them ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: the bluetooth device should be certified by apple's MFi Program. https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Answer (score 3):

1. An iOS app can receive data from any bluetooth device which must confirm the protocol of Bluetooth(GATT, ATT, L2CAP).
2. Bluetooth device can limit the device to connect by the data format(such as CRC, XOR), the device even can limit the special MAC address of bluetooth to connect if your app not sale on App Store

Below is a simple description to Core Bluetooth, please check the detail [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH2-SW1)

The bluetooth device is a Peripheral to produce data, iOS app is a Central that can receive data or send limited data to Central.

[image]

When the Peripheral begins advertise, the Central can search and connect to it, when the connection is build, Central can notify or read the Characters in Services of Peripheral

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An iOS app can connect to any device that supports the GATT profile with Bluetooth Low Energy/Bluetooth Smart using the Core Bluetooth framework.

Generally, a peripheral cannot prevent your app from connecting to the device, but your ability to read/interpret the data offered by the device will be limited by:

1. The documentation provided by the device vendor
2. Your ability to "reverse engineer" the information if documentation is not provided
3. Any handshake/security methods that the vendor may have implemented; For example the device may require your app to respond with specific data in response to data from the device - see point 2.

Devices that use legacy Bluetooth (i.e. not BLE) are only supported if they offer generic services such as audio - these are supported by the AV framework, or if they are MFi certified - these are supported by the External Accessory framework.